# Using spaceless in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code:

```
    {% for item in profile.jobs.all %}
        {% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Which produces something like the following:

```
"Programmer , Plumber , Philosopher"
```

I do not want the leading space before the comma, but the only way I've been able to get rid of it is to compress it onto one line, which reduces readability:

```
{% for item in profile.jobs.all %}{% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: I think that space is caused by space/indentation before `{% if not forloop.first %}` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{% spaceless %} only strips spaces between html tags.

You can either use {{ value|join:", " }}

or I believe this will work:

```
{% for item in profile.jobs.all %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try {% spaceless %} template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless

Comment: Thanks, could you please show the code for the above using {% spaceless %} ? (I tried wrapping it around the code and it didn't change anything).

Comment: -1, `{% spaceless %}` only works between HTML tags, not template tags.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use something like

```
{% if profile.jobs.count != 1 %}
    {% for item in profile.jobs.all %}
        {{ item }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{item}}
{% endif %}
```